# How to duplicate a legend in ggplot and edit content

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot where I need two different legends, one for the line and points on the top and one for the bottom. After duplicating it, I still need to change the title of the legend at the bottom and the p-values. I found a similar question but they were trying to duplicate the legend for multiple plots, not in the same figure.

I guess annotate could be a solution, but the I´d miss the figures in the legend.
[image]
Here is the code.

```
Kohljuvlength <- structure(list(Schwanzlänge = c(57, 59, 61, 62, 59, 58, 66, 
66, 60, 57, 59, 57, 60, 60, 61, NA, NA, NA, 54, 55, 56, 57, 55, 
58, NA, 55, 53, NA, 56, 65, 55, 58, 61), Flügellänge = c(73.5, 
77, 76, 76.5, 73.5, 73, 79.5, 77.5, 75.5, 76, 75.5, 72, 77, 77, 
78, NA, NA, NA, 73, 73, 73.5, 74, 73, 76.5, NA, 71.5, 72.5, 74, 
74.5, 78.5, 74.5, 73, 77), MSUG = c(0.127320513, 0.127320513, 
0.127320513, 0.127320513, 0.127320513, 0.127320513, 0.127320513, 
0.127320513, 0.127320513, 0.127320513, 0.127320513, 0.127320513, 
0.127320513, 0.127320513, 0.127320513, 0.40516414, 0.40516414, 
0.40516414, 0.670135128, 0.670135128, 0.670135128, 0.923284561, 
0.459573881, 0.506471961, 0.77669483, 0.77669483, 0.887765369, 
0.887765369, 0.439464666, 0.444201161, 0.444201161, 0.444201161, 
0.444201161), CUG1 = c(0.285793784, 0.285793784, 0.285793784, 
0.285793784, 0.285793784, 0.285793784, 0.285793784, 0.285793784, 
0.285793784, 0.285793784, 0.285793784, 0.285793784, 0.285793784, 
0.285793784, 0.285793784, 0.416844242, 0.416844242, 0.416844242, 
0.626013498, 0.626013498, 0.626013498, 0.881740188, 0.389679036, 
0.670881175, 0.83329158, 0.83329158, 1, 1, 0.578067543, 0.399895195, 
0.399895195, 0.399895195, 0.399895195)), row.names = c(NA, -33L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


lm4 <- lm(Kohljuvlength$`Schwanzlänge` ~ Kohljuvlength$MSUG, data = Kohljuvlength )
lm5 <- lm(Kohljuvlength$`Flügellänge` ~ Kohljuvlength$MSUG, data = Kohljuvlength )
lm6 <- lm(Kohljuvlength$`Schwanzlänge` ~ Kohljuvlength$CUG1, data = Kohljuvlength )
lm7 <- lm(Kohljuvlength$`Flügellänge` ~ Kohljuvlength$CUG1, data = Kohljuvlength )


ggplot(Kohljuvlength) + 
  geom_point(aes(MSUG, `Schwanzlänge`, color = "MSUG")) + 
  geom_abline(aes(slope = coef(lm4)[["Kohljuvlength$MSUG"]], 
                  intercept = coef(lm4)[["(Intercept)"]],
                  colour = "MSUG"))+
  geom_point(aes(CUG1, `Schwanzlänge`, color = "CUG1")) + 
  geom_abline(aes(slope = coef(lm6)[["Kohljuvlength$CUG1"]], 
                  intercept = coef(lm6)[["(Intercept)"]],
                  colour = "CUG1"))+
  geom_point(aes(MSUG, `Flügellänge`, color = "MSUG")) + 
  geom_abline(aes(slope = coef(lm5)[["Kohljuvlength$MSUG"]], 
                  intercept = coef(lm5)[["(Intercept)"]],
                  colour = "MSUG"))+
  geom_point(aes(CUG1, `Flügellänge`, color = "CUG1")) + 
  geom_abline(aes(slope = coef(lm7)[["Kohljuvlength$CUG1"]], 
                  intercept = coef(lm7)[["(Intercept)"]],
                  colour = "CUG1"))+
  xlab(expression(atop("Urbanitätsvariablen [%]", paste("Urbanicity variables"))))+
  ylab(expression(atop("Länge [mm]", paste("Length"))))+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(scale = 1*100), breaks = seq(0, 1.0, by = 0.2))+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.9))+
  scale_color_manual(name="Flügel - Wing", 
                     values=c("red", "black"),
                     labels=c("CUG1, p = 0.012", "MSUG, p = 0.007"))
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall I think the easiest (and clearest) approach would be to use facetting, use just one legend and add the p-values as labels inside the panel or the panel titles.

Be it as it is, to get a duplicated legend and at the same time have some flexibility to place the legends inside the plot, you could first create two separate plots, extract the legends from these plots via `cowplot::get_legend` and finally put them inside your main plot via e.g. `patchwork::inset_element`.

Either way I would suggest to first do some data prep to reshape your data to a longer form and to put the model coefficients in a dataframe. Additionally I use a small helper function for the `geom` layers.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
library(patchwork)

layer_fun <- function(what) {
  list(
    geom_point(
      data = filter(Kohljuvlength1, y %in% what),
      aes(xvalue, yvalue, color = x)
    ),
    geom_abline(
      data = filter(mods, y %in% what),
      aes(
        slope = slope,
        intercept = intercept,
        color = x
      )
    )
  )
}

pal_color <- c(CUG1 = "red", "MSUG" = "black")

labels_tail <- mods |> 
  filter(y == "Schwanzlänge") |> 
  select(x, labels) |> 
  tibble::deframe()
labels_wing <- mods |> 
  filter(y == "Flügellänge") |> 
  select(x, labels) |> 
  tibble::deframe()

p_tail <- ggplot(Kohljuvlength1) +
  layer_fun("Schwanzlänge") +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Schwanz - Tail",
    values = pal_color,
    labels = labels_tail
  ) +
  theme_classic()

p_wing <- ggplot(Kohljuvlength1) +
  layer_fun("Flügellänge") +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Flügel - Wing",
    values = pal_color,
    labels = labels_wing
  ) +
  theme_classic()

ggplot(Kohljuvlength1) +
  layer_fun(c("Flügellänge", "Schwanzlänge")) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = scales::label_number(scale = 100),
    breaks = seq(0, 1.0, by = 0.2)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("red", "black"),
    guide = "none"
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab(
    expression(atop(
      "Urbanitätsvariablen [%]",
      paste("Urbanicity variables")
    ))
  ) +
  ylab(expression(atop("Länge [mm]", paste("Length")))) +
  theme(
    strip.text.x = element_blank(),
    strip.background.x = element_blank()
  ) +
  patchwork::inset_element(
    cowplot::get_legend(p_tail),
    top = .4, right = .9,
    bottom = .4, left = .8
  ) +
  patchwork::inset_element(
    cowplot::get_legend(p_wing),
    top = .9, right = .9,
    bottom = .9, left = .8
  )
```

[image]

**Data Preparation**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

Kohljuvlength1 <- Kohljuvlength |>
  pivot_longer(c(Schwanzlänge, Flügellänge),
    names_to = "y", values_to = "yvalue"
  ) |>
  pivot_longer(c(MSUG, CUG1),
    names_to = "x", values_to = "xvalue"
  )

mods <- Kohljuvlength1 |>
  nest(data = ends_with("value")) |>
  mutate(
    mod = map(data, ~ lm(yvalue ~ xvalue, data = .)),
    coeff = map(mod, broom::tidy)
  ) |>
  unnest(coeff) |>
  select(y, x, term, estimate, p.value) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = term, values_from = c(estimate, p.value)) |>
  select(y, x, intercept = 3, slope = 4, pvalue = 6) |> 
  mutate(
    labels = paste(
      x, scales::label_pvalue()(pvalue),
      sep = ", "
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This does the trick, but when I try to use `ggarrange` to fit a total of 5 plots in a A4 page, the legends are so big that the one at the top cuts a little bit the lines and hides some points. I tried moving it a little bit in the last `patchwork` lines but it does not seem to help. Do you know if it is possible to make the font slightly smaller? Thanks again!

Comment: Sure. You could set the font size for the legend titles or text via theme options, e.g. `+ theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 10), legend.text = element_text(size = 8))`. The defaults are 11 and .8 * 11 respectively. And of course do you have to add the theme adjustments only for the legend plots.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!! I could also move it now. Thanks!!